# Adding space after every 3rd number in input

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to add space after every 3rd number, but this code doesn't work if the input is `type="number"`. Does someone know how to modify the code to make it work even for `type="number"`
? Here is my input:

```
<input type="number" id="phone" autocomplete="off" placeholder="(+420)">
```

And also here is the script:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^\dA-Z]/g, '').replace(/(.{3})/g, '$1 ').trim();
});
</script>
```

Comment: If it has spaces in it it's not a number.

Comment: Use `type=tel`.

Comment: css might be a better option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function insertBlankAfterEveryThreeCharacters(str) {
  var str=str.split(" ").join("").split("");
  var formatted=[];
  while(str.length) {
    for(var i=0; i<3 && str.length; i++) {
      formatted.push(str.shift());
    }
    if(str.length) formatted.push(" ");
  }
  return formatted.join("");
}
```

Use in your event:

```
this.value=insertBlankAfterEveryThreeCharacters(this.value);
```

```js
document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  this.value=insertBlankAfterEveryThreeCharacters(this.value);
});

function insertBlankAfterEveryThreeCharacters(str) {
  var str=str.split(" ").join("").split("");
  var formatted=[];
  while(str.length) {
    for(var i=0; i<3 && str.length; i++) {
      formatted.push(str.shift());
    }
    if(str.length) formatted.push(" ");
  }
  return formatted.join("");
}
```

```html
<input id="phone">
```

`<input type="number"...` makes it so you can go up/down one = I assume not an intended result...
Your place holder has parentheses and a plus in it - It is not what you seem to be wanting in the solution...